# Populate <p> tags with JSON data for in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each, for-in-loop

I'm trying to target 18 $('.char-names') elements and dynamically populate with names from a local JSON file. The 3 console log's are showing 18 different id, charName, ingName, so the data is linking. It just populates $('.char-names') with the same name in every slot. I'm pulling my hair out here.

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
    for (var i in data) {
        var charName = data[i].name;
        var imgName = data[i].image;
        var id = data[i].id;
        console.log(id);
        console.log(charName);
        console.log(imgName);

        $('.char-names').text(charName);
    }
});
```

The HTML...

```
<div class="faces-container">
    <img src="img/face1.jpg" class="faces">
    <p class="char-names"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean... `$('.char-names')` selects **all** `.char-names` elements, and `.text(charName);` updates the text content of **all selected elements** to the value of `charName`. it's doing exactly what you told it to do... Maybe you should filter down to a specific .char-names element based on an index?

Comment: Why not generate the `<p>`s (or the entire `<div>`s) dynamically? That would be flexible in case you have too much or too few entries in the JSON!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters don't use `for in` on arrays.

You can use the index of the `$('.char-names')` elements if they  are indexed the same as the array data

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
    var $charNames =  $('.char-names');
    $.each(data, function(i, obj){
          $charNames.eq(i).text(obj.name);
    });
});
```

If the indexing is not the same then not enough detail is provided in question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. I have not tested it

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
    var charNamesArray = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        var charName = data[i].name;
        var imgName = data[i].image;
        var id = data[i].id;
        charNamesArray.push(charName);
    }
});

var charNames = document.getElementsByClassName('char-names');
for(var i = 0;i < charNamesArray.length;i++){
    charNames[i].innerHTML(charNamesArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is ajax which is asynchronous. You can't process the data before it is received

Answer (score 0):

It's better to dynamically generate those elements since the entries of the JSON object could be of any length. So your JS should be:

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
    // the container
    $container = $('#container');
    // $container.empty(); // if you want to empty it first
    for (var i in data) {
        var charName = data[i].name;
        var imgName = data[i].image;
        var id = data[i].id;

        var $name = $('<p>' + charName + '</p>').addClass('faces');
        var $img = $('<img src="' + imgName + '"/>').addClass('char-names');
        var $div = $('<div></div>').append($img)
                                   .append($name)
                                   .addClass('faces-container');
        $container.append($div);
    }
});
```

And your HTML should have an empty element (that will be filled dynamically):

```
<div id='container'></div>
```